# What does clEnqueueWriteBuffer really do?

Tags: opencl

While trying to improve the performance of some OpenCL computation, I used the profiling features of the OpenCL runtime on a clEnqueueWriteBuffer call, and on the immediately following clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (which depends on the previous data tranfer):

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmdq, cl_buf, CL_FALSE, 0, size, data, 0, NULL, &write_ev);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdq, ker_with_cl_buf_as_input_param, 2, NULL,
    work_sze, local_sze, 1, &write_ev, &ker_ev);
```

Here is what is returned by clGetEventProfilingInfo (I substracted the initial time and converted to micro seconds) :

```
           QUEUED   SUBMIT    START      END   END-START
write_ev        0  113.952  120.448  211.136      90.688
ker_ev    130.016  132.608  217.280  515.200     297.920
```

My questions are:

1. Why does clEnqueueWriteBuffer not return before the memory transfer has been started or submitted ?
2. More importantly, why does it take so long for the transfer to be actually submitted ???

It seems to me that 22% performance could be gained just if the memory transfer could start immediately.
Does clEnqueueWriteBuffer copy the data in another host memory region before actually doing the transfer ?

Additional information:

I use the cuda 4.1 framework on a Tesla M2090 GPU.

The buffer is created previously using:

```
cl_buf = clCreateBuffer(my_context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, size, NULL, NULL);
```

EDIT: clEnqueueReadBuffer does not exhibit such behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use pinned memory as described in Section 3.1.1 of [NVidia OpenCL Best Practices Guide](http://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/CUDABrowser/downloads/papers/NVIDIA_OpenCL_BestPracticesGuide.pdf).

They do not mention if a copy is performed in case pageable memory is used, but it may happen.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, when using pinned memory, this large delay disapears. So the driver might either copy data, or do something else to transfer from regular memory that takes some time...

Answer (score 2):

The write should make a few checks before start the asynchronous copy. This checks includes valid buffer type in parameters, misalign of buffers, allocation of buffers to write on,...etc.

In the clEnqueueWriteBuffer function, only is asynchronous the raw copy of data, but the preparation isn't.

Comment: @natchouf the read hasn't the same checks, nor the reservation of buffers to write

Comment: well, this is certainly true for the first use of the buffer (where the write actually takes longer), but I doubt it for subsequent reuse...